# False attribution to increase authority

Tags: rhetoric

What is the practice called of falsely attributing an anecdote or piece of writing or fact to another source to give it more authority or authenticity, or to avoid the appearance of self-promotion?

Ex.: Making up an aphorism and labeling it as 'an old French proverb', misattribution of Sarah Williams' quotation, "I have loved the stars too fondly to be fearful of the night" to Galileo.

Comment: There is a mountain of *misattribution* out there, much of it by authors unknown. But I suppose what you are looking for here, is a clear case of original composition.

Comment: Why not simply call it  - Intellectual theft -take without referencing from someone else's writing or speech- or plagiarism?

Comment: But isn't this the opposite of 'intellectual theft' which amounts to stealing someone else's ideas. Here you are falsely handing something over to Abraham Lincoln, not borrowing or taking from him.

Comment: Intellectual fraud. Literary fraud.

Comment: The simplest word for this is a lie.

Comment: @BlessedGeek - That's what Plato and Aristotle used to call it...

Answer (score 3):

[Pseudepigraphical](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pseudepigraphy) is used by some biblical scholars.

Comment: You misspelled it! :)

Comment: It's a long word for me!!!!!!!

Comment: Me too - I had to have *two* goes at the edit to get it right! :)

Comment: That is very impressive. If your link actually worked I'd upvote.

Comment: @Tim Link fixed, upvote away. (The link was actually Fumble’s addition, so that one's on him.)

Comment: +fumblefingers: "I had to have two goes ..." Two gos or two goes?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a case of counterfeiting credentials, to me. The phrase turns up a number of uses [on Google](https://www.google.co.jp/search?newwindow=1&espv=2&q=counterfeit%20credentials).

The practice itself is simply lying. Coloring it with a specific phrase depends on the exact situation.

Comment: Copyright Infringement ?

Answer (score 0):

While the dictionaries I own don't contain it, I think the word *apocryphy* is exactly what you're looking for.

Derived from the word *apocryphal* which means  “of doubtful authenticity but usually accepted as being true”, I’d use it in a sentence like this:

> Attributing your dad’s old saying to Albert Einstein just to win that argument was one of the worst acts of *apocryphy* I've ever seen.

A real word that does exist, but is much less satisfying, is *made-up* —  as in, “I just made that up about Einstein having said that.”

Comment: Apocrypha is in the dictionary to and is more widely used. It does however have the meaning of just false.

Comment: Is *Apocrypha* an apocryphy? Acropophy. Acrophypha. Acrobaticryptopherical.